# Making a device that can detect the salinity of water

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, voltage, sensor

This is my second year trying to attempt to make a device for Science Olympiad and I am confused on how to even start. I understand an Arduino is necessary but for the rest I'm lost.

How do I detect the salinity of water with something that is legal and how to read the voltage?

Comment: Are you asking us to design the system for you, or just point you in the direction as to how to detect salinity of water? If the latter: the amout of salt in water changes its conductivity. So one option is to simply measure the conductivity of the water which can be done with a known voltage across two poles in water and measuring the current (or known current and measuring the votlage).

Comment: An arduino is hardly necessary; you could do this with pretty much any microcontroller, or even an all-analog circuit if you wanted to.

Comment: I don't understand this *something that is legal*

Comment: @MiNiMe I think OP is referring to legal within the rules of the Science Olympiad.

Comment: [Gravity: Analog Electrical Conductivity Sensor /Meter V2](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1123.html) is an example of a sensor which _electrical conductivity of an aqueous solution_ which I think can be converted into _salinity_. Only mentioned that specific example as has some example code which runs on an Arduino Uno.

Comment: George, it is not our responsibility to know the rules or legality of devices in the competition you are entering. You will need to state the requirements and ask a specific question about an electrical engineering issue. As currently written, the scope is far too broad to be answerable in a concise way.

Comment: @JYelton Yeah, makes sense. Ta

Comment: Did you try doing an online search for "salinity test circuits" ? - There are actually hundreds of them.  If you start with one circuit and get stuck return here and others can help you work out any problems, or just show us what have tried in the past. If you don't show an effort on your part people here are less likely to offer help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good place to start: get two glasses of water, one with salt dissolved and one with no salt. Get a multimeter and place the probes in the water about a centimeter apart and measure the resistance for each. You'll see that one has a higher resistance than the other.

Now you'll need to translate this experiment to an Arduino. There are many online tutorials out there that will tell you in great detail how to measure a resistance with an Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

Most people trying to solve this kind of design immediately think about the conductivity of salt water vs unsalted water.  Especially as this is *Electronics* focussed.

But you might also consider the density, and build a sensor based on that property, which varies by [roughly 20%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saline_water) according to the salinity.

- **Idea 1: floating samples** Based on the idea of a [Galileo thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_thermometer), you could have a plastic bag (of negligible weight) filled with water of known salinity (that you made).  This will sink in water that is less saline, and float in water that is more saline.  Make say eight bags of different salniities.  The use some method (interrupted light beams?) to see which are floating and which are not.  It would be big of course, but would suit measuring the salinity of a tidal basin or similar.  The direct calibration is a benefit, as would be the temperature-insensitivity.  (Explaining why this wouldn't measure temperature is a very good thing to show the understanding of the physical properties.)  You might have eight GPIO inputs on your microcontroller, each with a photosensor, as an illustration of the interface.
- **Idea 2: force exerted on a mass** Based on the idea of a conventional [hydrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrometer).  Get a mass, submerse it in the liquid suspended on a [spring scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_scale), and see what it weighs.  By [Archimedes principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) the weight will be lower submersed in the water than in the air; but also, it will be different depending on the density of the water, which is dependent on salinity (yay!) but also on temperature (boo!).  You'd have to find a way to get the reading from the spring scale, and a method of measuring temperature to correct for that.  Instead of interfacing to a spring scale, you could consider a [strain gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge), and you'll easily find tutorials on how to interface those.

Once you have a basic sensor, you start thinking about how to integrate it with a microcontroller of whatever kind.  You mention Arduino, which is certainly a possibility, specifically as it is designed for newcomers to control engineering it might be one of the easiest (and has lots of tutorials for interfacing anything you can think of).  But almost any microcontroller could be used, and Atmega and ESP32 in Arduino worlds are common starting points.  You could also consider Raspberry Pi or perhaps Pi Pico for a different emphasis.